# Drupal 7 Feed Import

Tags: mysql, drupal, import, feed

I am now struggling for hours but I cannot get my feed import to run properly.
The strange is, that I can import data for the normal fields in Drupal like "Title" or "Language" or "User". But for my custom fields like "field_produkt_beschreibung", no entries are made in Drupal. Even if I supply a Standard Value for the field:
[image: standard value set to "Standardwert"]

The standard value is not saved in the node.

```
{
"entity": "node",
"settings": {
    "uniq_path": "SKU",
    "preprocess": "",
    "feed": {
        "protect_on_invalid_source": 0,
        "protect_on_fewer_items": "0"
    },
    "processor": {
        "name": "default",
        "class": "FeedImportProcessor",
        "options": {
            "items_count": "0",
            "skip_imported": 0,
            "updates_only": 0,
            "reset_cache": "0",
            "throw_exception": 1,
            "max_reported_errors": "100",
            "break_on_undefined_filter": 0,
            "skip_defined_functions_check": 0,
            "uniq_callback": "",
            "after_save": "",
            "before_combine": "",
            "after_combine": "",
            "before_create": "",
            "before_save": ""
        }
    },
    "reader": {
        "name": "sql",
        "class": "SQLFIReader",
        "options": {
            "dsn": "mysql:dbname=d****7;host=localhost",
            "user": "d******7",
            "pass": "*****",
            "query": "SELECT * FROM mytable",
            "params": ""
        }
    },
    "hashes": {
        "name": "sql",
        "class": "FeedImportSQLHashes",
        "options": {
            "ttl": 0,
            "insert_chunk": 300,
            "update_chunk": 300,
            "group": "produkte_h_lter"
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "name": "default",
        "class": "FeedImportMultiFilter",
        "options": {
            "param": "[field]",
            "include": ""
        }
    },
    "fields": {
        "title": {
            "field": "title",
            "column": false,
            "paths": [
                "Produktname"
            ],
            "default_action": 0,
            "default_value": "Standardwert",
            "update_mode": 0,
            "filters": {
                "\u00fc": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&uuml;",
                        "\u00fc",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "\u00e4": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&auml;",
                        "\u00e4",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "\u00d6": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&Ouml;",
                        "\u00d6",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "\u00f6": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&ouml;",
                        "\u00f6",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "\u00df": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&szlig;",
                        "\u00df",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "R": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&reg;",
                        " ",
                        "1"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "prefilters": []
        },
        "field_produkt_hersteller_raw": {
            "field": "field_produkt_hersteller_raw",
            "column": true,
            "paths": [
                "//Hersteller"
            ],
            "default_action": 0,
            "default_value": "kein Hersteller",
            "update_mode": 0,
            "filters": [],
            "prefilters": []
        },
        "field_produkt_link": {
            "field": "field_produkt_link",
            "column": true,
            "paths": [
                "Link"
            ],
            "default_action": 0,
            "default_value": "Standard",
            "update_mode": 0,
            "filters": [],
            "prefilters": []
        },
        "field_produkt_artikelnummer": {
            "field": "field_produkt_artikelnummer",
            "column": true,
            "paths": [
                "Artikelnummer"
            ],
            "default_action": 0,
            "default_value": "Standardwert",
            "update_mode": 0,
            "filters": [],
            "prefilters": []
        },
        "field_produkt_beschreibung": {
            "field": "field_produkt_beschreibung",
            "column": true,
            "paths": [
                "Beschreibung"
            ],
            "default_action": 0,
            "default_value": "Text",
            "update_mode": 0,
            "filters": {
                "\u00fc": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&uuml;",
                        "\u00fc",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "\u00e4": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&auml;",
                        "\u00e4",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "\u00d6": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&Ouml;",
                        "\u00d6",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "\u00f6": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&ouml;",
                        "\u00f6",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "\u00df": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&szlig;",
                        "\u00df",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                "R": {
                    "function": "FeedImportFilter::replace",
                    "params": [
                        "[field]",
                        "&reg;",
                        " ",
                        "1"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "prefilters": []
        }
    },
    "static_fields": {
        "type": "produkt",
        "uid": "3",
        "language": "de",
        "field_produkt_shop": {
            "tid": "20"
        },
        "title": "Test"
    },
    "functions": []
}
```

}

I really would appreciate a hint, about what might be wrong with my setup. Thank you very much,
Simon

Comment: Is there anything in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

It was missing filters and umlaute (ä, ö...) in the text fields. It is working now